# Flex display: make a column width as content

Tags: html, css

I have a simple two columns layout:

- on the left there is some text
- on the right there are one or more link buttons

Here my code

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.left-column {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.right-column {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button-link {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-column">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <a class="button-link">A link button</a>
    <a class="button-link">Another link button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the width of the right column to be no bigger than the size of the largest button (in this case the second one `Another link button`).
The text on the left takes up the whole remaining space.
The text inside the link button should not be on a new line.

| How it is | How it should be |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: remove `align-items: center;` from right column

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, but buttons should not be bigger than their content

Comment: that's not what your screenshot is showing

Answer (score 1):

Check this one

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.left-column {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex:auto;
}

.right-column {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
flex:1;
}

.button-link {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-column">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <a class="button-link">A link button</a>
    <a class="button-link">Another link button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .container {
        padding: 20px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        display: flex;
        gap: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .left-column {
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .right-column {
        border: 1px solid tomato;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .button-link {
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you but have a look to the second row of the table in my main message: button links should not be bigger than their content

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice this part ! I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Just add flex:1 button-link e.g:

```
.button-link {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    **flex: 1;**
}
```